# Sinch gUM error on HTTPs website

Tags: javascript, sinch

I am using a sample Video JS from Sinch and the gUM refused to work with camera and microphone on insecure origin. I went on to get my client to purchase SSL certificate so that the Video/Microphone work on the browser. However, this is the error I get.
Is there any work around as I already got them to purchase ssl.

Here is the console error :-

```
 sinch.min.js:5 Error retrieving media stream     NavigatorUserMediaErrorconstraintName: ""message: "Only secure origins are allowed ."name: "PermissionDeniedError"__proto__: NavigatorUserMediaErrorconstraintName: (...)get constraintName: ()arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: ""__proto__: ()<function scope>constructor: NavigatorUserMediaError()arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: "NavigatorUserMediaError"prototype: NavigatorUserMediaError__proto__: ()<function scope>message: (...)get message: ()name: (...)get name: ()Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "NavigatorUserMediaError"__proto__: Object(anonymous function) @ sinch.min.js:5
 sinch.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: GET "http://ps15.pubnub.com/time/0?uuid=0eae9a07-d6f6-4ef3-82db-b8d93713a660&pnsdk=PubNub-JS-Web%2F3.7.2".l @ sinch.min.js:2k @ sinch.min.js:2PN_API.la.time @ sinch.min.js:1s @ sinch.min.js:1
```

Answer (score 0):

No thats built in to chrome, no way of getting around that

Comment: But it says in the error, that https would be required to operate microphone. And interestingly it works fine on localhost within chrome browser. How does it not work online on a dedicated server ?

Comment: If you check the chrome docs, localhost is excluded. Anyway, it's a chrome restriction that you can do nothing about. Trust me on that;)

Comment: I trust you on that and I appreciate your answer, would you be able to tell me if I need ssl for Firefox or IE 10.